How to Type a Python Factory Function That Returns a Class with Typed Class Methods
I’m having trouble typing a Python factory function that returns a class with correctly typed class methods.
For a concrete example, I have a factory function, Factory(), which creates a CRUD class with a class method .create(). The Factory() function takes two parameters:

model: a SQLAlchemy model class, representing a table
schema: a Pydantic schema class

from typing import Type, TypeVar

from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


SqlModel = TypeVar("SqlModel", bound=Base)
PydanticSchema = TypeVar("PydanticSchema", bound=BaseModel)


def Factory(model: Type[SqlModel], schema: Type[PydanticSchema]):
    class Foo:
        @classmethod
        def create(cls, data: schema) -> model:
            db_model = model(**data.model_dump())
            return db_model

    return Foo


class MyModel(Base):
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)


class MySchema(BaseModel):
    name: str


MyFactory = Factory(MyModel, MySchema)
bar = MyFactory.create(MySchema(name="bar"))

I want to use these two classes both in the .create() method’s body and in its typing, so that when I instantiate a class from the Factory function, the .create() method is typed with the model and schema classes that were passed to Factory.
In the example:

With TypeVar and Type, I get data typed as MySchema@Factory and the return type as MyModel@Factory, but this does not seem correct as it doesnt link to the original class types and their methods
Without TypeVar, both are typed as Any.

How can I type this so that when calling MyFactory = Factory(MyModel, MySchema), MyFactory.create() has the correct argument annotation of MySchema and return type of MyModel?
EDIT 2024-11-08 09:43:00 UTC
I think I may managed to do this with the help of generics and double typing of TypeVar, but I am by no means certain this correct/abusing the type system so any feedback would be great:
SqlModel = TypeVar("SqlModel", bound=Base)
PydanticSchema = TypeVar("PydanticSchema", bound=BaseModel)


def Factory(model: Type[SqlModel], schema: Type[PydanticSchema]):
    FooSqlModel = TypeVar("FooSqlModel", bound=model)
    FooSchema = TypeVar("FooSchema", bound=schema)

    class Foo(Generic[FooSqlModel, FooSchema]):
        @classmethod
        def create(cls, data: FooSchema) -> FooSqlModel:
            db_model = model(**data.model_dump())
            return db_model

    return Foo[model, schema]


You can't statically type Factory's return with a class created within a function via nominal typing. The idea doesn't make sense - every time you run the function, you get a different class. I don't see the reason why your code is written like this, but if you really need to embed Foo within Factory, Factory's return type can only be annotated by a typing.Protocol.

Understood but I am not looking to type the class itself, only the methods. So that when I pass in different model/schema pairs I get the correct typing on the methods for arguments and returns.

A class with only one method is usually an anti-pattern. create doesn't even use its cls argument; just return an ordinary function.

The Class Way
As others have stated, embedding create as a method of Factory is really the way to go - you still get the same nice syntax, it fixes all of the typing issues, and it's shorter:
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Generic

from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


SqlModel = TypeVar("SqlModel", bound=Base)
PydanticSchema = TypeVar("PydanticSchema", bound=BaseModel)

class Factory(Generic[SqlModel, PydanticSchema]):
    def __init__(self, model: type[SqlModel], schema: type[PydanticSchema]) -> None:
        self._model = model
        self._schema = schema

    def create(self, data: PydanticSchema) -> SqlModel:
        db_model = self._model(**data.model_dump())
        return db_model


class MyModel(Base):
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)


class MySchema(BaseModel):
    name: str


MyFactory = Factory(MyModel, MySchema)
bar = MyFactory.create(MySchema(name="bar"))

The Protocol Way
If you really really need it to be a separate class...it can be done with a Protocol:
from typing import Generic, Protocol, TypeVar

from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


SqlModel = TypeVar("SqlModel", bound=Base, covariant=True)
PydanticSchema = TypeVar("PydanticSchema", bound=BaseModel, contravariant=True)

class FooLike(Protocol, Generic[PydanticSchema, SqlModel]):
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, data: PydanticSchema) -> SqlModel:
        ...

def Factory(model: type[SqlModel], schema: type[PydanticSchema]) -> "type[FooLike[PydanticSchema, SqlModel]]":
    class Foo:
        @classmethod
        def create(cls, data: PydanticSchema) -> SqlModel:
            db_model = model(**data.model_dump())
            return db_model

    return Foo


class MyModel(Base):
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)


class MySchema(BaseModel):
    name: str


MyFactory = Factory(MyModel, MySchema)
bar = MyFactory.create(MySchema(name="bar"))

Hope this helps!
